# How do I exclude numbers that have 5 as a digit in the hundredths in java

Tags: java

I am fairly new to java and I am looking for a more effective solution to my problem. I have a list of numbers that goes from 1 to 10 000 and need to exclude every number that is multiples of 3 (easy enough) and every number that has 5 in the hundredths, so excluding 500-599, 1500-1599, etc. I have a solution but I think it isn't efficient. Would it be possible to break numbers into Strings and exclude those that have 5 as a number in the hundredths so I would not have to write the same statement for 1500-1599, 2500-2599, etc

```
for (int ii = 500; ii <= 599; ii++) {
    if (a == ii) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can divide by 100 and check if the remainder after dividing by 10 is 5.

```
if (i / 100 % 10 != 5){
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = String.valueOf(a);
If(s.length>2 && s.charAt(s.length-3)=='5')
{ 
  return false;
}
```

If I have not messed up the syntax, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

A generic approach

```
// value = (number % (10^position)) / 10^(position - 1)
// if (value != 5) {

for (int number = 399; number < 701; number += 10) {
    if (number % (int) Math.pow(10, 3) / (int) Math.pow(10, 2) != 5) {
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

After calculating powers and replacing them in the if the condition becomes equal to @Unmitigated's approach.